# Event Handling for UI elements generated from a DataTemplate in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, datatemplate

I'm struggling to find out how to respond to any event other than a button click (I can use Command to deal with them).

If create a ToggleSwitch from a DataTemplate how would I generate a "Toggled" event?

Comment: what do you mean by how would you response to your Toggled event? Identifying which of the DataTemplated dynamically generated toggle button raised the event?

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase my question. I need to _generate_ an event from a dynamically generated ToggleSwitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Microsoft documentation [ToggleSwitch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch)

***XAML:***

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleSwitch Header="Toggle Switch Example" 
            OffContent="Do work" OnContent="Working" 
            Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>  
        <ProgressRing x:Name="progress1"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

***Code-Behind:***

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as ToggleSwitch;
            if (toggleSwitch != null)
            {
                if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
                {
                    progress1.IsActive = true;
                    progress1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    progress1.IsActive = false;
                    progress1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see in XAML you defined a Toggled event handler to handle with to changes in it's state. 
The event handler is automatically created in code-behind, and you can add your logic to it.

In this example, you cast your sender object to the ToggleSwitch, which you know was the type of the object which raised this event, and by checking it's properties you can infer for instance if the Switch is On/Off, and handle that state properly, like it is being done in the example above.

***Dynamically generated ToggleSwitch with event:***

Lets imagine our customers is an ObservableCollection property, which you have defined as the DataContext of your page. Dependending on it's size, we would have the same number of ToggleSwitch showing up on your page, and all of them would redirect to the *ToggleSwitch_Toggled*.

```
         <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding customers}" Width="350" Margin="0,5,0,10">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ToggleSwitch Header="Toggle Switch Example" 
                            OffContent="Do work" OnContent="Working" 
                            Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Is this what you are looking for? It might not be the most useful implementation yet, since there is still no implemented logic in order to understand which of the dynamically created ToggleSwitch raised the event (all call the same eventhandler).

**Behaviour:**

[image]

Comment: That would work if the ToggleSwitch wasn't generated dynamically. Unfortunately this won't work in my case.

Comment: @rawturtle Updated the answer.

Comment: The problem with this solution is If I define the ToggleSwitch_Toggled function it will never be fired when I use the toggle. I can currently only generate events from buttons by using the Command="MyCustomEventHandler" and passing data around this way. No idea how to get it going for any other UI elements though.

Thanks for putting in the time to help me out.

Comment: I am testing it on VS2017 and what i mentioned is working perfectly fine!

Comment: Updated with a GIF showing the same EventHandler being invoked by different ToggleSwitch.

Comment: Hmm it didn't work for me when I was trying it this way. Although I didn't have DataContext set to my equivalent of customers. The only other difference I had is that my XAML is in a resource dictionary and uses a TemplateSelector to pick which DataTemplate to use at runtime. I'll marked it as solved because in terms of the question I asked you have answered it.
Thanks for your time and effort